# Using customuser in django as foreignkey to model leads to .OperationalError: (1005, "Can't create table (errno: 150)")

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have created a custom user in my django project that inherits from AbstractBaseUser and PermissionsMixin.

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, username,  password, is_staff, is_superuser, email=None, **extrafields):
        now = timezone.now()
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must specify a username first")
        if email:
            email = self.normalize_email(email)

        user = self.model(username=username, email=email, is_superuser=is_superuser,
                      is_staff=is_staff, is_active=True, last_login=now,
                      date_joined=now, **extrafields)

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, username, password=None,  email=None, **extrafields):
         return self._create_user(username, password, False, False, email=email, **extrafields)

    def create_superuser(self, username, password, email=None, **extrafields):
        return self._create_user(username, password, True, True, email=email, **extrafields)


class MyCustomUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), max_length=254, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    #more custom user fields
```

I have set the settings attribute

```
settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL = "users.MyCustomUser"
```

and used this user as a ForeignKey to another model

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    creator =  models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    another_model = models.ForeignKey(AnotherModel)
```

When I run the migrate function it gives me the error described on the title. If i comment out creator field it works (so only the creator foreignkey is causing an issue). I didn't have this problem with sqlite3 and and Django 1.6. I am now in Django 1.8.x and changed to MySQL (locally for developement)and having this issue. Has something changed?

Comment: Please put the whole traceback inside post content, instead of an error message in the title.

Comment: Works now. I had to create migrations first for the application contained the Customer model "makemigrations customers" and then migrate worked as it should.